# C# subtracting one list from another or checking if one list is completly containt in another list

Tags: c#, .net, list

How to subtract one list from another?

```
  List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "abc", "abc", "abc", "def" };
  List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "abc" };
  var r = l1.Except(l2).ToList();
```

Doing this results in r => "def"
instead of r=> "abc", "abc", "def".
I mean, the second list only contains "abc" one time. So I want to remove only one instance of "abc" of the first list.

Btw: Is there a way to check if one list is completely contained in another list?
Meaning when list1 only contains "abc" one time and list2 contains "abc" two times, list2 is not contained in list1. `Except` doesn't work with multiple values.

Comment: If the second list contains two instances of "abc", should two instances be removed from first list?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Although I'm not sure, what should happen when there are 4x "abc". Maybe some kind of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own extension method *MyExcept*

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyExcept<T>(this IEnumerable<T> orgList, IEnumerable<T> toRemove)
{
    var list = orgList.ToList();
    foreach(var x in toRemove)
    {
        list.Remove(x);
    }
    return list;
}
```

As per `Alexei Levenkov`s comment, a little improvement...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyExcept2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> orgList, IEnumerable<T> toRemove)
{
    var list = orgList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    foreach (var x in toRemove)
    {
        var inx = list.BinarySearch(x);
        if (inx >= 0) list.RemoveAt(inx);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Side note: this will be insanely slow for large lists due to O(n*m) complexity, fine and easy to read for small lists.

Comment: I did some benchmarking and have to say that for relatively small lists (10 and 10 entries), the first approach is by far the fastest. With lists (200 and 30 entries) the first approach and the version from dasblinkenlight are similar. When the lists get larger, the variant from dasblinkenlight is the fastest. Since I only have less then (10 and 10 entries) the first suggestion from L.B is the right one for me. The second improved version lost in all my tests.

Comment: the best thing is it also works for duplicate items in either of the lists. I am using this to find out if all items of one list exist in another list.

Answer (score 5):

`Except` does not work, because it treats its operands as sets.

One approach to solving this would be creating counts, subtracting them, and then re-creating the list:

```
// Make word counts for l1 and l2
var c1 = l1.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var c2 = l2.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
// Make a count of the difference between the two
var diff = new Dictionary<string,int>();
foreach (var p in c1) {
    int sub;
    if (!c2.TryGetValue(p.Key, out sub)) {
        sub = 0;
    }
    diff[p.Key] = p.Value - sub;
}
// Reconstruct the result from counts
var res = diff.SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Repeat(p.Key, p.Value)).ToList();
```

This algorithm is O(M+N)

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/sXkIzN)

Comment: Side note: if order is important than one would need to use something else than dictionary for final step - i.e. iterate original list and carefully filter out items paying attention how many left.

Answer (score 2):

The List's Remove method removes the first occurrence of the string in the list:

```
        List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "abc", "abc", "abc", "def" };
        List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "abc", "abc" };
        foreach (string sl2 in l2)
        {
            l1.Remove(sl2);
        }
```

As a result, l1 contains just "abc" and "def" in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a custom code for this one, something like this :

```
private void SubstractList(ref List<string> l1, List<string> l2)
        {
            foreach (string s2 in l2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (l1[i] == s2)
                    {
                        l1.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You can do better, this is just an example ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = l1.Distinct().Except(l2).ToList();
```