# List Remove and Except behave differently

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to subtract one C# string List from another one. I use two separate solution and both does not make sense when I look at my original list count and subtract list count amount and the result.

Result changes in each solution and both does not give the right number.

Solution 1:

- Original list count: 2398 , tempListUnifier , this is a C# string  List
- Removal List count: 930, removalList, this is a C# string List
- Result: 1365

  ```
  var result = tempListUnifier.Except(removalList);
  ```

---

Solution 2:

- Original list count: 2398 , tempListUnifier , this is a C# string  List
- Removal List count: 930, removalList, this is a C# string List
- Result: 1481

  ```
  var result = tempListUnifier;

  foreach(string item in removalList)
  {
      result.Remove(item);
  }
  ```

---

I wonder why do I get different result in both solution? Actually I want to get the real result, which is  2398 - 930 = 1468 . How is this possible?

Comment: Are both lists unique? My guess is that the original list has about 100 strings that are duplicated, so more than 930 elements are getting removed.

Comment: `subtract one C# string List from another one` do you mean remove a string from a list?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378524/c-sharp-subtracting-one-list-from-another-or-checking-if-one-list-is-completly-c?rq=1

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  yes, remove a string from a list

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8 the documentation does help, have you read it?

Comment: Perhaps, if someone is marking your question as a duplicate based on the title instead of the content, it would be a good idea for you to [edit] the title?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I wonder why do I get different result in both solution?

Most likely because `tempListUnifier` contains strings that are duplicated. When you call `Except`, *all* strings that are present in the "remove" list are removed, so if "cat" is found 3 times in the original list and is present in the remove list (even once), *three* strings will get removed.

In the second example, you most likely either have some duplicates in the *removal* list or some words are in the removal list that are not in the original list, or a combination of both. Since `Remove` only removes the *first* matching element, you don't have the effect from duplicate strings that you have in the `Except` method.

Comment: Thank you D Stanley, your explanation makes sense, I do have duplicates in my templistUnifier, and Except is the solution that I need rather than Remove.

Answer (score 0):

D Stanley answered your question absolutely correctly. I’ll try to explain why this is so.

`Except` method from your first solution works as follows: the elements of both collections are added to the set, which does not add the element to the collection if it already exists (this way the set cannot contain duplicates), and then the elements of the set are lazily returned as the result.

`Remove` method from your second solution works differently. The `IndexOf` and `RemoveAt` methods are used in the implementation of this method. However, the documentation of the `IndexOf` method says:

> Searches for the specified object and returns the zero-based index of **the first** occurrence

Thus, `Remove` method deletes also only the first occurrence.

Comment: Thank you Stanislav Molchanovsky for providing additional details into Stanley's explanation.